# Detect a click on DIVs with unpredictable IDs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several `div` tags and I'm trying to detect which one clicked. Each result has a unique title, but the same id. How do I use `.click()` to know which one was clicked so I can get it's ID and use it?

Comment: Are you saying there are multiple divs with same id at the same time on the page? How are you registering the click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div').click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This one checks if the `div` has `img` as a child and then triggers the click.

```
$('div:has(img)').click(function(){
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener that captures clicks using the parent > child methods. For instance:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="result" title="df45fds46"></div>
   <div id="result" title="48df6sfsd"></div>
</div>
```

Then on the javascript:

```
$("#parent div").click(function(){
   console.log(this.attr('title')); // or $(this).attr('title'), i'm not quite sure
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Id: " + event.toElement.id);
    alert("Title: " + event.toElement.title)
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/VSDCL/3/)